# Vue.js doesn't render dynamic img with v-bind:src

Tags: vue.js

I can't render dynamic images using `v-bind:src="require('.....')"/>`.
I've an array of string that represents my images paths.

I'm obtaining from vue:

> Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module"

but the path is correct.

This is my template:

```
<img class="card-img img-size"
                      v-bind:src="require(wineriesLogos[index])"/>
```

If I substitute `wineriesLogo[index]` with its value, it works.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

This is my project structure:
[image: Project structure]

This is my variable that contains images paths:

Comment: why can't you use require ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using require. I made a mistake during question writing...I've updated!